# Both registering signal handler for SIGSEGV and still being able to create full crash dump from OS

Tags: linux, crash-dumps, sigaction

We are using the standard pattern of registering custom signal handler for SIGSEGV with [sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and then when segmentation fault occurs using the [backtrace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) function to walk the stack and print it to some file. It is nice feature to have the backtrace in logs but it disables the OS writing the full dump of the crashed program which is more than useful. How is it possible to both catch the SIGSEGV, do custom handling, and also cause the OS to create the full dump as it would be in case of default action?

Can I for example call remember the oldact pointer to default handler (as described in man), and then call it directly from out custom handler? Needless to say we need crash to indicate the exact place where it happened. So for example re-registering handler to old value and implicitly crashing the program in other place would not work.

Comment: You can just return from the handler after resetting `sigaction`.

Comment: @Ruslan returning from handler will cause infinite loop

Comment: If you have reset the handler to the default, then it'll just fault again and dump core

Comment: @Ruslan sorry missed the "resetting sigaction", yep that seams to be working. Wanna put it as a answer?

Comment: Have done already, scroll down a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the sigaction after having handled the signal. Then the faulting instruction will re-run after returning from the handler, and fault again, leading to core dump.

Here's an example:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sigaction oldSA;
void handler(int signal)
{
    const char msg[] = "Caught, should dump core now\n";
    write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, sizeof msg - 1);

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &oldSA, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa={0};
    sa.sa_handler=handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, &oldSA);

    int* volatile p=NULL;
    *p=5; // cause segfault
}
```

Example run:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test && ./test
Caught, should dump core now
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: One important comment on this solution. It will cause inconsistent behavior when using the raise of kill functions . Because this solution relies on execution of the same instruction and then proceeding to the default handler, after it was restored in custom handler. kil and raise have no problem with proceeding which effectively will cause the program to proceed instead of creating the dump.

Comment: @Boris indeed. The signal should be raised/sent twice in a row in this use case. This might be not easy with library functions though, if they e.g. `abort`...

Comment: @Boris in fact, you can raise the signal from the handler directly, after you've reset to defaults. See also a related question: [Segfault in SIGSEGV handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33743599/673852)

Comment: Is it possible to use this when running the application using `gdb --args`? I've tried and the handler doesn't get called.

Comment: @intrigued_66 If you want to pass the signal once, just use `continue` command after stopping on a segfault. This will pass the signal and result in calling the handler. If you want GDB to ignore all `SIGSEGV` signals, i.e. not stop the application on raising them, you can use `handle SIGSEGV nostop` before `run`.