# Can GDB call user-defined signal handler and still break on the code which threw a signal?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have a Linux C/C++ application, including a custom signal handler which sends an email.

When I run without GDB and a signal is thrown, my signal handler is called.

However, when I run using GDB it obviously intercepts the signal and my handler is not called. I presume this is so it can show the backtrace etc.

Is it possible to have both? I'd like to see where the code died (and if possible, the interactive stack) but I'd still like my handler called, to send the email.

I tried this method:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sigaction oldSA;
void handler(int signal)
{
    const char msg[] = "Caught, should dump core now\n";
    write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, sizeof msg - 1);

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &oldSA, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa={0};
    sa.sa_handler=handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, &oldSA);

    int* volatile p=NULL;
    *p=5; // cause segfault
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69988396/1107474

but unfortunately my handler works without GDB but doesn't get called when used with GDB.

Comment: I hope you're not actually sending an email in the signal handler. You can only make calls to *async-signal-safe* functions in a signal handler. Read [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03) and [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), especially the parts about the only functions that are safe to call from within a signal handler.

Comment: Yes, probably. In `gdb`, do `info signal` You can manipulate these table values with the `handle` command. However, please see my answer: [C handle signal SIGFPE and continue execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432614/5382650) as to why you should be careful with this. You _can_ do async-signal-safe calls from within the handler, but you want to abort before leaving.

Comment: @CraigEstey What is it I should instruct GDB to do with these signals? I don't want to ignore them, I just want my handler called first before GDB pauses.

Comment: [Crudely] An alternative is to have the program set up a shared memory area [or SysV IPC msg queue]. It should `fork`. The parent is the "watchdog". When the child gets a `SIGSEGV`, the handler can set a flag in the shared memory area. It goes into an infinite loop. The parent sees this flag, and takes whatever action is appropriate: send email, force child to core dump, etc. It then sends the child a `SIGKILL` I've done a more elaborate version of this in real, mission critical, production code.

Comment: I presume you want: `handle SIGSEGV stop pass` But, that may stop the program before passing the signal (I can't remember what the order is, so just give it a try). Another way: `handle SIGSEGV pass nostop`. Then, `b i_got_segv` In the handler, do what you want. You then call `i_got_segv`. This is defined as `void __attribute__((noinline)) i_got_segv(void) { __asm__ __volatile__("nop" ::: "memory"); }`

Comment: @CraigEstey Is there any way my handler can send the email and then <do something> so GDB is triggered, as if my custom handler had never existed?

Comment: @intrigued_66 I believe what you're asking for is the `i_got_segv` trick I mentioned. Or, do the "watchdog" approach. Please reread my link as to why you _don't_ want to do aggressive things in a signal handler, _particularly_ after a `SIGSEGV`. I've had great success with the watchdog process (and shared memory) in commercial products.